# Rails sublime text shortcuts for view pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext

Are there any sublime text plugins for rails that give short cuts for snippets like:

```
<%= %>
```

Maybe other ones for for.each loops etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by writing customized sublime text snippets as per your needs and usage.

To create a snippet, GOTO Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet

**Example 1**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<%= $0 %>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>var</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
    <description>ERB var</description>
</snippet>
```

The above snippet will be invoked when you type **"var"** and will automatically insert **"<%=  %>"** with the cursor right between the braces where we have specified $0 in the snippet.

You can type your variable name to complete the statement.

If a placeholder needs to be inserted, then **$0** can be replaced with **${0:varname}**. Here the placeholder is **varname**

**Example 2**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<% ${1:@Items}.each do |${2:item}| %>
    $0
<% end %>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>each</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
    <description>ERB each</description>
</snippet>
```

The above snippet will be invoked when you type **"each"** and will automatically insert a basic each block.

The $ variables represents the fields over which you can navigate by pressing the tab key.

Refer http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html for more sytax on snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Just write "pe" (without quotation marks) and press Tab.